# Wait for querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing an app via Ionic Framework. I upgraded my app from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4. Now hyperlinks do not work anymore. The HTML content is loading dynamically based on the chosen page. 
I've read I have to set new eventListeners for my clicks on my `a` elements.

I am trying:

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.objAnswerService.getAntworten(objFrage).then(arrAnswer =>
    {
        this.arrAnswers = arrAnswer;
    }
}

ngAfterViewInit()
{
    console.log('_enableDynamicHyperlinks');
    this._enableDynamicHyperlinks();
}

private _enableDynamicHyperlinks()
{
    let arrUrls = this._element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arrUrls)); // No elements
    console.log(arrUrls); // Correct elements
    arrUrls.forEach((objUrl) =>{
        console.log('do something'); // Never reached because 0 elements
    });
}
```

answer.page.html

```
<div *ngIf="arrAnswers">
    <div *ngFor="let objAnswer of arrAnswers"
         class="antworten">
        <div *ngIf="objAnswer"
             class="antwort">
            <div [innerHTML]="safeHtml(objAnswer.strText)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I wait for querySelectorAll() to find all existing elements?

Comment: can you share more context of your code? what is that native element, what is your template? where are those a elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since `this.arrAnswers` is initialized in a Promise it is undefined when the component fiirst loads. As a result of this `<div *ngIf="arrAnswers">` evaluates to false and there are no elements for `querySelectorAll` to return on `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` because they both gets called once during component [lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).

what you need is [ngAfterViewChecked](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked) to be called when `this.arrAnswers` is initialized and dom is updated.

```js
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('_enableDynamicHyperlinks');
    if (!this._element) return;
    let arrUrls = this._element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('p');
    console.log("arrUrls.length:", arrUrls.length);
    console.log("arrUrls:", arrUrls);
  }
```

also do not forget to use `{ static: false }` on `@ViewChild` as explained [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description).

here is a simple [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3ugn4)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! If I use 
@ViewChild(ElementRef, { static: false }) _element: ElementRef;

I get the error:

[ng] ERROR in src/app/answer/answer.page.ts(19,30): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ static: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'.
[ng]   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'static' does not exist in type '{ read?: any; }'.
https://pastebin.com/XkcqW0AM

Comment: which angular version are you using? `{ static: false }` applies to angular8.

Comment: I guess I am using 7.3.4 because of the line "_from": "@angular/cli@7.3.6"" in node_modules/@angular/cli/package.json

Comment: try removing `{static: false}`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LTseAXz.png

this is my console. Seems like this._element is always false now.

Comment: can you share current full component.ts file and component.html. because i tried my solution with angular7 [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-viewencapsulation-so9qzm) and it works.

Comment: i don't see any code in pastebin related to the question

Comment: thats my app.component.ts and .html or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: i mean the component which contains the code you provided in your question

Comment: The first one is the code from my page.ts or do you mean another file?
https://i.imgur.com/dxlV4nQ.png

Comment: answer.page.ts please

Comment: ok. change `@ViewChild(ElementRef) _element: ElementRef;` to `@ViewChild("elem") _element: ElementRef;` in answer.page.ts then change `<div *ngIf="arrAnswers">` to `<div #elem *ngIf="arrAnswers">` in answer.page.html and delete `ngAfterViewInit` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is my current consolelog: https://i.imgur.com/SZNAkF4.png
Can I change it that ngAfterViewChecked triggers only one time after all is loaded and not that often?

Comment: ok built myself a workaround. Can you please check if my addEventListener is correctly build? Because I get 5412212112121212 from line 112 but my Click Listener isn't working

Comment: if this answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted and open a new question for your problem with addEventListener because it is a whole another problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to handle this is using angular [lifecycle hook.](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

If it doesn't work with `ngOnInit()` you can take a look at `ngAfterViewInit()`which *respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views / the view that a directive is in.*

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   let arrUrls = this._element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');

    console.log(JSON.stringify(arrUrls)); // No elements
    console.log(arrUrls); // Correct elements

    arrUrls.forEach((objUrl) =>{
        console.log('do smthng'); //Never reached because 0 elements
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think problem is not the time I am calling my querySelectorAll but that querySelectorAll isn't finished before I call .forEach.
I tried it your way and It didn't change anything.