# EventListener doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I updated my ionic3 to ionic4 and hyperlinks aren't working anymore. So I tried to set a new ClickEvent for them. Unfortunately the click event doesn't work. The content of my event is never reached even If I click some link. I don't get why it's not working.

```js
ngAfterViewChecked() {
 if (!this._element) return;
 let arrUrls = this._element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
 console.log("arrUrls.length:", arrUrls.length); // Reached and correct
 console.log("arrUrls:", arrUrls); // Reached and correct
 this.setEventListener(arrUrls);
}


private setEventListener(arrUrls)
{
 arrUrls.forEach((objUrl) =>
 {
  console.log('5412212112121212'); // Reached
  console.log(objUrl); // Reached and correct
  // Listen for a click event on each hyperlink found
  objUrl.addEventListener('click', (event) =>
  {
   //NOT REACHED
  
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('7213983728912798312231'); // Isn't reached
   //this._link = event.target.href;
  }, false);
 });
}
```

Comment: `this._element` should be... What exactly? What does `console.log(this._element)` says?

Comment: Why don't you use the `(click)=""` event?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717820/wait-for-queryselectorall
That is my current output: https://i.imgur.com/J9ZxCeE.png

Comment: @TomasVancoillie what do you mean? I don't know this usage

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to get so detailed and write this all yourself.

Other people have already solved the problem such as the LinkifyJS project.

There is an angular compatible wrapper for it:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-linkifyjs

Which, once you have done the standard setup process you can use it as either a pipe:

```
<span [innerHTML]="'Linkify the following URL: https://github.com/anthonynahas/ngx-linkifyjs and share it <3' | linkify"></span>
```

Or as a service:

```
import {NgxLinkifyjsService, Link, LinkType, NgxLinkifyOptions} from 'ngx-linkifyjs';

constructor(public linkifyService: NgxLinkifyjsService) {

  const options: NgxLinkifyOptions =
     {
      className: 'linkifiedYES',
      target : {
          url : '_self'
        }
      };

  this.linkifyService.linkify('For help with GitHub.com, please email support@github.com');
  // result 1 --> see below

  this.linkifyService.linkify('For help with GitHub.com, please email support@github.com', options);
    // result 2 --> see below
 } 
}
```